# Is it ok to install a new outlet on the in a wall shared with a bathroom?

Tags: electrical, receptacle

My main floor living room has an inner wall with no outlets, and I would like to add one.

The outlet will most-likely be running off a 15amp circuit. The 14/2 wires will be coming straight through the floor from the basement and pretty much run vertically right into the outlet box.

On the other side of the wall in question, is a bathroom. The toilet, sink and bathtub faucet are not near the wall in question, and there is no plumbing in the wall either.

I am a little worried about moisture possibly affecting the outlet in the future. Should it be ok to install the new outlet?

Comment: Absolutely OK. But, if the moisture from the bathroom is getting behind the bathroom's **dry** wall, you already have other problems :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's no particular issue nor code rule with installing outlets in a wall *shared with* a bathroom.

So, go ahead, don't be excessively concerned with unlikely edge cases.

*In the bathroom itself* requires GFCI protection, normally, but is not otherwise a problem as far as code is concerned, for that matter.